# Plot linear equations/inequalities in Julia

Tags: julia

Suppose we have couple of linear inequalities like `2x-5y<=6` and `x+y>=0`, how do we plot the two inequalities? To extend this, if we have multiple such inequalities how do we try to solve this graphically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isolating y shows us that both are inequalities of the form `y>=ax+b`. This means that we can plot the inequalities using plots, functions for the equality versions, and the maximum values the function obtains on the intervals.

```
using Plots
f(x) = (2/5)x-6/5
g(x) = -x
X = -10:10
the_max = max(f(X[end]), g(X[1]))

plot(X, f, fill = (the_max, 0.5, :auto))
plot!(X, g, fill = (the_max, 0.5, :auto))
```

Which gives us
[image]

Had the second equation had its inequality flipped, we would have

```
using Plots
f(x) = (2/5)x-6/5
g(x) = -x
X = -10:10
the_max = max(f(X[end]), g(X[1]))
the_min = min(f(X[1]), g(X[end]))
plot(X, f, fill = (the_max, 0.5, :auto))
plot!(X, g, fill = (the_min, 0.5, :auto))
```

Obviously, you would want to automate the precedure of finding the min and max if there were many such inequalities to plot. Also, this rewriting depends on the linearity, but your question specifically mentioned they were linear.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can try `ImplicitEquations`:

```
using ImplicitEquations, Plots
f(x,y) = 2x - 5y - 6
g(x,y) = x + y - 0
plot((f < 0) & (g > 0))
```

Resulting in the region over the default rectangle [-5,5], [-5,5]:

[image: rendered image]

Comment: I am getting MethodError: no method matching isless(::typeof(f), ::Int64)

Comment: To avoid type piracy, the operators `>` and `<` have been replaced by unicode symbols `\gg[tab]` and `\ll[tab]` (Or `Lt(f, 0) & Gt(g, 0)`).

Comment: Sorry I do not understand what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a matrix of `x` and `y` on the interval you want to plot (using a version of `meshgrid`), and then let `u=(2x-5y.<=6)` and `v=(x+y.>=0)`. Then `u` will be 1 when the equation is satisfied, same for `v`. You can use a heatmap, contour plot, or scatter plot from Plots.jl to then plot the `(x,y,u)` and `(x,y,v)` (you will see if you chose a fine enough grid by how coarse the plot is). For the overlap, you can plot `z=(u.==v)`.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at IntervalConstraintProgramming.jl (still very much a work in progress...)

Comment: That package looks great.

Comment: Dear @David, Can we use "IntervalConstraintProgramming.jl" to draw a 3D plot? If yes, could you please share any example of a 3D plot?